# Why a SWITCH...CASE not taking 'char'?

Tags: c#

I have two questions with this code:

```
public int InsertOrUpdateRecord(char _code, string _databaseFileName)
{

   switch(_code)
   {
      case 'N':
           // Some code here

       case 'U':
           // Some code here
   }
       return 0;
}
```

1. It is not accepting **char** single quote and double quote value.
2. If I pass _code as **string**, it gives red underline in *case* with this error:

**Control cannot fall through one case label to another.**

Comment: You are just missing the break key work for each case - see Elisha's code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason for the compilation error is that the `case` is missing the `break`

```
switch (_code)
{
    case 'N':
    // Some code here
        break; // break that closes the case

    case 'U':
    // Some code here
        break; // break that closes the case
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a `break` at the end of the case:

```
switch (_code)
{
    case 'N':
        // Some code here
        Console.WriteLine("N was passed");
        break;
    case 'U':
        // Some code here
        Console.WriteLine("U was passed");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want in either cases to do the same like so:

```
switch(_char) {
    case 'N':
    case 'U':
      // Common code for cases N and U here...
}
```

You have to specifically tell the compiler where the case statement halts:

```
switch(_char) {
    case 'N':
        // Code here...
        break; // The N case ends here.
    case 'U':
        // Code here with different behaviour than N case...
        break; // The U case ends here. 
}
```

The `break` statement tells the compiler that you're done with that case, and that it has to get out of the `switch` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

you can either write a break or return statement like the below code.

char _code = 'U';
                switch (_code)
                {
                    case 'N':

```
                case 'U':
                    return;
            }
```

OR,

char _code = 'u';
                switch (_code)
                {
                    case 'N':

```
                case 'U':
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no problem with `char`. See this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/843c4c28.aspx) about your error.